# What should I included (using maven) to have use an embedded sesame repository in my Java application

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, sesame

I would like to use an embedded openRDF sesame repository in my Java application. I can not find information what is a minimum set of libraries that I need to include -- place in my pom.xml -- in my Java application to have it running. Can anybody give me a hint or a link to a website that would help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an "include everything and the kitchen sink" maven dependency for Sesame:

```
groupId: org.openrdf.sesame
artifactId: sesame-runtime
```

That includes the entire framework. If you want to trim that down and only include specific features, you can instead add specific dependencies on subparts. For example, if all you need is a simple in-memory triplestore, you could probably do with adding these two dependencies:

for the repository API:

```
groupId: org.openrdf.sesame
artifactId: sesame-repository-sail
```

for the actual storage backend:

```
groupId: org.openrdf.sesame
artifactId: sesame-sail-memory
```

Comment: You need also include slf4j-*, e.g., slf4j-simple, to your pom.xml to have memory sesame repository running.

Comment: Ah good point. Just to make it clear: you need to add a dependency on a slf4j logger imlpementation (like slf4j-simple, logback, or slf4j-log4j). You should also take care to add _exactly_ one logger implemeantation (so don't just chuck all the available loggers in there, it will have nasty consequences for logger configuration).

Answer (score 1):

Check the Maven Repository Browser and search for [openRDF](http://www.mvnbrowser.com/artifacts-search.html?page=1&search=openrdf).